# beforeSave action is not triggered ajax-request

Tags: php, ajax, yii, request

I found that in Yii 1.1.14 if I save object without form submiting(actually that is ajax-request) then beforeSave action is not triggered.
So next lines raise error that created_at is required and empty:

```
$Tour_Highlight_Model = new Tour_Highlight;
$Tour_Highlight_Model->name = $name;
$Tour_Highlight_Model->tour_id = $tour_id;
// $Tour_Highlight_Model->created_at = new CDbExpression('NOW()'); // MUST BE UNCOMMENT
$ActionResult = $Tour_Highlight_Model->save(); // BUT VALIDATION IN MODEL WORKS!

public function beforeSave() {
  if ($this->isNewRecord) {
    $this->created_at = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
  }
  return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

What is the matter ?

Comment: That may be validation error thrown?? $model->validate(); ??

Answer (score 0):

Validation of model runs before save event is raised, so you need to use beforeValidate() instead of beforeSave().

But it is better to place your code into controller, not into model.

```
if ($this->isNewRecord) {
    $this->created_at = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
  }
```